# fastest way to check if linq query returns results

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

I do not need to know the actual results or even a count - just if the result is null or not.

I am currently doing it like this and then looking at the count:

```
int itemsNeedingUpdated = 
    (from i in cDb.DistributionLineItems
     where (i.CompanyNo == item.dt_company_no && i.UniqueIdNo == item.Unique_Id_No) &&
            (i.DatetimeUpdated >= startingDateTimeToSearch) &&
            (i.ReceivingScanPieces > 0 || i.LoadingScanPieces > 0 || i.ActualPieces > 0)
     select i.UniqueIdNo).Count();
```

but as this is going to churn through a lot of times I want to know if this is the fastest way to check this?

Using EF 6 against Azure SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
bool itemsNeedingUpdated = 
    (from i in cDb.DistributionLineItems
     where (i.CompanyNo == item.dt_company_no && i.UniqueIdNo == item.Unique_Id_No) &&
           (i.DatetimeUpdated >= startingDateTimeToSearch) &&
           (i.ReceivingScanPieces > 0 || i.LoadingScanPieces > 0 || i.ActualPieces > 0)
     select i.UniqueIdNo).
     Any();
```

Which will bail out as soon as an item matching the predicate is found.

Comment: It is complaining:

Error CS0742 A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.If I add the select back in will that negate the usefulness of it?

Comment: @JoeRuder Please try the updated code, I had forgotten you need a projection in case of query syntax.